# Encontrar el punto mas cercano, a un feature de tipo Point en c# con Arcobjects Desktop

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de intersecar 2 capas, La cual cuando es de tipo Point le aplico un buffer para encontrar los puntos que estén a 2 metros, Pero a la hora de extraer el ITopologicalOperator3 me lo trae nullo y me marca error en la consulta, He estado investigando un poco y al parecer es porque la geometría de los puntos es diferente.
en el caso cuando el feature es de tipo lineal me lo esta haciendo correctamente con el código que tengo

```
            if (LayerIntersec != null)
            {
                IElement polygonElementFeature = null;
                if (FeaturePoly.Shape is IPoint)
                {

                    ITopologicalOperator3 bufferFeature = FeaturePoly.Shape as ITopologicalOperator3;
                    polygonElementFeature = new PolygonElement();
                    polygonElementFeature.Geometry = bufferFeature.Buffer(2);

                }
                else
                {
                    ITopologicalOperator3 bufferFeature = FeaturePoly.Shape as ITopologicalOperator3;
                    polygonElementFeature = new PolygonElement();
                    polygonElementFeature.Geometry = bufferFeature.Buffer(2);
                }

                ISpatialFilter QSFParcel = new SpatialFilter();
                QSFParcel.Geometry = polygonElementFeature.Geometry;
                QSFParcel.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelContains;
                ///
                IFeatureCursor pFeatureCursor = LayerIntersec.Search(QSFParcel, false);

                while ((pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                {

                    int index = pFeature.Fields.FindField("Text");
                    var valor = pFeature.Value[index];
                    string TextoCop = Convert.ToString(valor);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo 2 capas que obtengo de un archivo CAD, una de puntos y una textos(LayerIntersec), las cuales por cada punto que exista necesito aplicarle una consulta espacial basada en la capa de textos para encontrar el texto mas cercano al punto y poder guardarlos en unos string.

Comment: Le estoy aplicando un buffer pero a la hora de generar el ITopologicalOperator3(bufferFeature) me lo trae como nullo, investigue un poco y al parecer es porque la geometria es diferente ,                                                                                    ITopologicalOperator3 bufferFeature = FeaturePoly.Shape as ITopologicalOperator3;
polygonElementFeature = new PolygonElement();
 polygonElementFeature.Geometry = bufferFeature.Buffer(2);